# nginx: Specify custom headers in rewritten location blocks

Tags: nginx, configuration, http, cache, http-headers

I'm trying to set some headers only for specific `location` blocks in nginx.

The problem I have is that those `location` blocks contain `rewrite` statements, which apparently seem to drop the custom headers.

In this example, I have two rules I want:

- Files inside `/static` should have `expires max;` (which sets the headers `Cache-Control: max-age=some huge value` and `Expires: some future date really far off`) and have their names be rewritten to something that doesn't contain `/static`
- Files everywhere else should have `Cache-Control: public` (no `max-age`)

Here's the configuration I tried:

```
server {
    listen [::]:80;
    root /somepath;
    location /static {
        expires max;
        rewrite /static(.*) /whatever$1;
    }
    add_header Cache-Control public;
}
```

And having the following directory structure:

```
/somepath
/somepath/f1.txt
/somepath/static/f2.txt
```

Then we get the following:

- `f1.txt`: `Cache-Control: public`, no `Expires` header
- `f2.txt`: `Cache-Control: public`, no `Expires` header

That's valid for `f1.txt` but not `f2.txt`. I want it to be like this:

- `f1.txt`: `Cache-Control: public`, no `Expires` header
- `f2.txt`: `Cache-Control: max-age=some huge value`, `Expires: some future date really far off`

The problem, I think, stems from the `rewrite /static(.*) /whatever$1;` line, which makes nginx cancel the headers it has added so far and then add them again (thus re-adding `Cache-Control`). As such, a trivial workaround would be this:

```
server {
    listen [::]:80;
    root /somepath;
    location /static {
        rewrite /static(.*) /whatever$1;
    }
    location /whatever {
        expires max;
    }
    add_header Cache-Control public;
}
```

The problem is that in my real config file, the `rewrite` isn't as friendly-looking as that. The rewritten URL is **not easily matchable** in a way that wouldn't also match some files that shouldn't have `expires max`, so I can't really use this workaround.

Is there a way to make those headers stick after a `rewrite`?

**EDIT**: Here's what my real URLs look like:

```
location ~ /(?:posts-)?img/.*-res- {
    access_log               off;
    expires                  max;
    rewrite                  "/img/(.*)-res-.{8}(.*)" /img/$1$2;
    rewrite                  "/posts-img/(.*)-res-.{8}(.*)" /posts/$1$2;
}
```

While I can add a `location` block for `/img` which would take care of files rewritten using the first `rewrite` rule, I cannot add one for the second one (`/posts`) because some files in `/posts` are not cacheable resources and thus shouldn't have `expires max`.

**EDIT 2**: Full config (or at least containing all the relevant parts):

```
server {
    listen [::]:80;
    root /somepath;
    server_name domain.tld;
    location ~ /(?:posts-)?img/.*-res- {
        access_log               off;
        expires                  max;
        rewrite                  "/img/(.*)-res-.{8}(.*)" /img/$1$2;
        rewrite                  "/posts-img/(.*)-res-.{8}(.*)" /posts/$1$2;
    }
    add_header Cache-Control public;
}
```

Directory structure:

```
/somepath
/somepath/img/f1.png
/somepath/posts/post1.html
/somepath/posts/d1/f2.png
/somepath/posts/d2/f2.png
```

Expected behavior according to HTTP request:

- `GET /somepath`: Serves `/somepath` with `Cache-Control: public`
- `GET /somepath/img/f1.png`: Serves `/somepath/img/f1.png` with `Cache-Control: public`
- `GET /somepath/img/f1-res-whatever.png`: Serves `/somepath/img/f1.png` with the headers sent by `expires max`
- `GET /somepath/posts/post1.html`: Serves `/somepath/posts/post1.html` with `Cache-Control: public`
- `GET /somepath/posts/d1/f2.png`: Serves `/somepath/posts/d1/f2.png` with `Cache-Control: public`
- `GET /somepath/posts-img/d1/f2-res-whatever.png`: Serves `/somepath/posts/d1/f2.png` with the headers sent by `expires max`

Comment: proxy_pass'ing to self works, but that's not really a solution.  Perhaps you could use 'alias'?

Comment: `alias` would work in the simple example above but unfortunately it wouldn't work in my real example, because the filename changes (from `something-somehash.extension` to `something.extension`)

Comment: Added how the URLs look like in my real config

Comment: can you share the full config

Comment: Added working config and sample directory structure and expected behavior for those files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work (I verified this with somewhat simpler config, though).  Igor Sysoev recommends to use regex locations as little as possible, by the way.

```
    location /img {
        if ($arg_max) { expires max; }
        ...
    }

    location /posts-img {
        if ($arg_max) { expires max; }
        ...
    }

    location ~ /(?:posts-)?img/.*-res- {
        access_log               off;
        expires                  max;
        rewrite                  "/img/(.*)-res-.{8}(.*)" /img/$1$2?max=1;
        rewrite                  "/posts-img/(.*)-res-.{8}(.*)" /posts/$1$2?max=1;
    }
```

Comment: Very good, also notice that `?max=1` parameter is not exposed to end users, and can be named as you like.

Comment: However, be wary that if you have other headers set in the first and second `location` blocks, they won't work... along with many other cases; `if` is listed as unsafe https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/

Answer (score 0):

For case insensitive [location matching](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location).

```
location ~* /static/
```

case insensitive remove the " ***** "

```
location ~* /static/
```

Source Nginx location directive [documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location)

Comment: Sorry but I don't think you understood the question. I'm not asking about case sensitive/insensitive matching here...

Comment: I think Sameer is right: just change  "location /static" to  "location  ~ /static"

Comment: You want to append headers based on a condition, so you'll have to match/search for it.

Comment: The "append header based on a condition" part works, the original URL (`/static/something`) is matched. What doesn't work is that the added headers do not stick after the `rewrite` rule. Additionally, because the rewritten URL doesn't match `/static` (so `location ~ /static` won't catch it), the header isn't added again after the rewrite.